# What are the frequencies in Hertz of the "bins" that AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData() returns?

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am currently working on a project that uses JavaScript's WebAudio API to show a graph of the frequencies in the audio. AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData() fills an Array which is divided into "bins", each with a  frequency range. I would like to know what frequencies (measured in Hertz) those "bins" correspond to.

I've tried interpreting each bin as a 1Hz step, but that clearly isn't right.

Comment: look at frequency bins in FFT you should get an in depth answer

Comment: Have you looked at this from a DSP (Digital Signal Processing) perspective?  There are well known rules such as sampling rate, using anti-aliasing filters (if the analog signal is availabe) and so forth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [MDN docs for `AnalyserNode.getByteFrequencyData()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData):

> Each item in the array represents the decibel value for a specific frequency. The frequencies are spread linearly from 0 to 1/2 of the sample rate. For example, for `48000` sample rate, the last item of the array will represent the decibel value for `24000` Hz.

The sample rate can be obtanined from the `sampleRate` property on the `AudioContext` (inherited from `BaseAudioContext`):

> The `sampleRate` property of the `BaseAudioContext` interface returns a floating point number representing the sample rate, in samples per second, used by all nodes in this audio context. ([docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BaseAudioContext/sampleRate))

You can set the sample rate of an `AudioContext` when it is created, via the `options` parameter of the constructor.

You can set the window size of the FFT of an `AudioAnalyzer` at creation via the `options` parameter of the constructor and any time after via the `fftSize` property.
From the [docs for AnalyserNode.fftSize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/fftSize):

> The `fftSize` property of the `AnalyserNode` interface is an unsigned long value and represents the window size in samples that is used when performing a Fast Fourier Transform (FFT) to get frequency domain data.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the sample.

> Each item in the array represents the decibel value for a specific
> frequency. **The frequencies are spread linearly from 0 to 1/2 of the
> sample rate**. For example, for 48000 sample rate, the last item of the
> array will represent the decibel value for 24000 Hz.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getByteFrequencyData